# Handling errors when consuming remote APIs

Tags: api, rest, error-handling

I have an RESTful API that calls another remote webservice. In general I have to query this remote service for every request that comes to my specific API function, and in my code I am wrapping and/or modifying parts of the result.

However it is possible that this remote service is not answering in time or throws an error. What is the most logical response that my API should throw then? I am specifically thinking about:

- HTTP 500 - however this gives the client no information what is happening
- HTTP 503 with a Retry-After header - then the client clearly sees this is an error and can query again later
- HTTP 200 and returning an empty result
- HTTP 200 and returning an error message or something like that

...or doing something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want your API to convey to your client.

**500**: client cannot fetch his resource and does not know whether he should just bombard your server with another request, but at least knows it MIGHT exist

**503**: client cannot fetch his resource, but at least knows it MIGHT exist and can retry later in X amount of time.

**200** **Empty response**: client is told his resource is empty and everything is ok, so probably will not come back while the resource could be not empty and was available a second later (Kind of misleading).

**200** **Error message**: client is told everything is ok, but receives in your context an error message. (This is wrong and totally contradicting itself/yourself!)

My advice:
Do the **503**